# Image capture of Windows mobile 5.0 camera using C# winform

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

I am trying to build an application to capture image from Windows mobile 5.0.
With Capture button, Zoom button and save button.
Please let me know if there is any reference

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check theses links

- [Code Samples for Windows Mobile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158662.aspx)
- [Camera API for Windows Mobile](http://dotnetref.blogspot.com/2007/07/camera-api-for-windows-mobile.html)